# systemException. Unable to serialize value. in row(s): 1

Tags: magento2.2, importexport

Whenever I try to import bulk amount of product data, it always throws an error as following: I have 10 thousand records in the csv.

[image]

I don't know what is causing the problem. Has anybody faced these kind of problem and resolved? If I click the **Download full report** link, it takes me to home page of import.

Comment: Have you check log file? system.log or exeception.log file?

Comment: There are no log files on the name.

Comment: I mean you need to check is there any log file generated at this place Magento Root->Var->Log->system.log or Exeception.log.

Comment: there is no log file generated at this name

Comment: Confirm log is enable from admin.

Comment: sorry, it is enabled in admin. The log is getting generated for other exceptions. But not for this issue. Any other clues?

Comment: What software are you using to create the CSV file? Could it be the wrong encoding? Make sure its `Unicode - UTF8`

Comment: The sheet looks the acceptable format. However if I have only just 2 or 5 records in the sheet and do import, it doesn’t throw any error. It happens only I try to do bulk import.

Comment: from the attached image, the last error says about the checked rows, checked entities, invalid rows and total errors. So I just kept only 2201 records and tried to run it. It doesn't throw any error. When it crosses more that 2201 then it is started throwing an error. Does Magento have any restriction to keep the limited records in the sheet?